# Writing a custom text at an arbitrary position in a chart

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I've created a nice chart but there's one thing missing. I'd like to be able to set a text somewhere in it. The optimal solution would be e.g. the current date smacked in huge yellow letters right in the middle of my graph.

I've googled for such a thing but none of the links ([proof that I've googled #1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2010/10/20/microsoft-dynamics-crm-dashboards-for-techies.aspx), [proof that I've googled #2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2011/01/04/crm-2011-charts-know-the-real-potential-part-i.aspx)) gave any hints on whether it's possible or not. In fact, the mock-up image in the second link **would** be something for me if the descriptions and arrows weren't drawn afterwards in an image processor.

NB. It's not a report at all. It's just a chart - a single, lonely chart - that displays values of a couple of series. I get to control the appearance, the legend etc. However, I'd like to put a floating text object (DIV formatable by CSS would be perfect), sprite, overlay, call it whatever you'd like, that will get its value from a given field (e.g. the current date).

And if I can position it freely anywhere over the graph, that'd be even "perfecter" but I'd settle for placement on form "top-right" or such. Alternatively, if there's an option to combine two "views" on top of each other or anything like that (I'm beating around the bushes with this).

Is that achievable and if so how?

Comment: How are you currently building your report?

Comment: I've tried to do that, as promised. But I failed. Not saying there isn't a way. Just saying it's not very commonly requested nor applied by anybody. Can that be done by IFRAME and/or likage to an external resource?

Comment: Nope. It's just a chart on placed on the dashboard. It communicates the current state of their project and it'd be neat if we could show the current progress as a single number baked into the chart. No report what-so-ever. :)

Comment: Right I get it now, I'll have a think.

Comment: Would it be feasible to catch the graphical result, embedding it somehow into a web resource (of type HTML) and then superimposing a DIV on top of that? The participation is quite non-existent here, despite the bounty, so I'm poking @AndreasJohansson too.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is a chart you have created using the CRM GUI, and apart from that it is totally uncustomised? E.g. have you opened up the XML of the chart and started changing anything?

Comment: @JamesWood Negative. I've created a basic chart but I needed to change its (colors, some other settings, etc.) properties and the options available through GUI is rather limited. So, I've edited the XML, yes. Suppose that I haven't - would you have a suggestions then? I'd expect that customization of a chart by editing its XML to be rather an advantage but maybe I should stand corrected. Do tell.

Comment: I think thats the path to go with, I just wanted to know what you currently had.

Comment: @JamesWood I'm starting to preparing myself for a no-no. I set bounty to double the usual size but the response is more than weak. Only you and one more replied and **he** seems to have gotten stuck entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I've had a play, a good dig around with the SDK, a bit of a google and this is the best I can come up with.

I know how to place text at arbitary positions on the chart, but only with static text, e.g. I don't know how to bind the text dynamically to anything - I suspect this is more to do with CRM than Charts, I couldnt find much documentation for CRM and Charts.

So I've found that [TextAnnotation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.textannotation.aspx) allow you to bascially place text wherever you like. This is contained within the`Annotations` collections.

For example:

```
<Chart>
  ...
  <Annotations>
    <TextAnnotation Text="This is an annotation" Name="TextAnnotation1" X="20" Y="50">
    </TextAnnotation>
  </Annotations>
  ...
</Chart>
```

So important to note that the position of the `TextAnnotation` is relative, e.g. the annotation will appear 20% of the width of the chart from the left. 0,0 is the top left corner. The MSDN has some more detail on [positioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456725.aspx).

So I can create a chart like this:

[image]

*HELLO WORLD!* is the annotation.

Using this xml:

```
<Chart Palette="None" PaletteCustomColors="55,118,193; 197,56,52; 149,189,66; 117,82,160; 49,171,204; 255,136,35; 97,142,206; 209,98,96; 168,203,104; 142,116,178; 93,186,215; 255,155,83">
  <Series>
    <Series ShadowOffset="0" IsValueShownAsLabel="True" Font="{0}, 9.5px" LabelForeColor="59, 59, 59" CustomProperties="PieLabelStyle=Inside, PieDrawingStyle=Default" ChartType="pie">
      <SmartLabelStyle Enabled="True" />
    </Series>
  </Series>
  <ChartAreas>
    <ChartArea>
      <Area3DStyle Enable3D="false" />
    </ChartArea>
  </ChartAreas>
  <Legends>
    <Legend Alignment="Center" LegendStyle="Table" Docking="right" IsEquallySpacedItems="True" Font="{0}, 11px" ShadowColor="0, 0, 0, 0" ForeColor="59, 59, 59" />
  </Legends>
  <Titles>
    <Title Alignment="TopLeft" DockingOffset="-3" Font="{0}, 13px" ForeColor="0, 0, 0"></Title>
  </Titles>
  <Annotations>
    <TextAnnotation Text="HELLO WORLD!" Font="Stencil, 15.75pt, style=Bold, Italic, GdiCharSet=0" Name="TextAnnotation1" X="20" Y="50" ForeColor="Orange">
    </TextAnnotation>
  </Annotations>
</Chart>
```

If that doesnt achieve your requirements I would suggest having a look at an SSRS report or some other custom piece IFramed into the dashboard.

Comment: Darn... The text **has to be** dynamically updated. At the moment I'm using an `IFRAME` element, sending out request and showing the updated text from an external source. That has three drawback, however. (1) It's rectum ugly programming-wise. (2) `IFRAME` is deprecated in HTML5 (I have no idea how MS is going to explain its usage in the future versions of CRM). (3) My solution only workd provided that the customer has an access to the internet - for an off-line/on-premise solution, they'll get a 400. And take a guess what set-up that certain customer has... Is dynamical refresh possible?

Comment: I dont know, I only worked out all the stuff with the annotation last night.

Comment: Are you loosing sleep for +100 reputation? (Just kidding, just kidding - I know you do that because you enjoy helping. Your karma is smiling, I'm sure.) I'll approve the +100 to you, of course, since your reply is the best one (not a steep competition, though - sadly). If you come up with something more (maybe based on what I posted in my previous comment), don't be shy. Otherwise, we'll have to conclude that it isn't doable, until proven otherwise. :(

Comment: Fyi, the closest I got to dynamic binding of values is that you can bind option set values as shown here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2011/05/02/crm-2011-charts-know-the-real-potential-part-deux.aspx  E.g. `Name="o:opportunity_statecode,1"`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check [this link](http://community.dynamics.com/product/crm/crmtechnical/b/crmteamblog/archive/2011/01/19/custom-charting-capabilities-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011.aspx) where they put descriptive text on a map. I haven't got that to work (didn't try very hard, either) but it's pretty easy to set just some text instead of a graph by the following code.

```
<visualization>
  <primaryentitytypecode>blobb</primaryentitytypecode>
  <name>My custom name</name>
  <webresourcename>MyCustomHttpFile</webresourcename>
</visualization>
```

I **would** be nice indeed to surprise a customer with a flash text sometimes so the idea is worth exploring. Strangely, I haven't found any good guide on how to do that.